# What is the meaning of the `greeter-export` setting in sound menu?

Tags: settings, indicator-sound

If you inspect `com.canonical.indicator.sound` with `dconf` you can see there are two settings

- `global-mute`
- `greeter-export`

Are they documented anywhere?
What is their precise meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [Schema file](https://github.com/linuxmint/indicator-sound/blob/master/data/com.canonical.indicator.sound.gschema.xml) from the Linux Mint GitHub page:

```xml
<key name="greeter-export" type="b">
  <default>true</default>
  <summary>Whether or not to export the currently playing song to the greeter.</summary>
  <description>
    If enabled the sound indicator will export the current player and
    song to the greeter so that it can be shown if the user is selected
    and the sound menu is shown.
  </description>
</key>
<key name="global-mute" type="b">
  <default>false</default>
  <summary>Initial setting for global mute (mute all) on the menu </summary>
  <description>
    On start up volume should not be muted.
  </description>
</key>
```

I'm pretty source Canonical have the sources posted somewhere online, but the Linux Mint sources are enough for our purposes.

Comment: Thanks. `global-mute` is still a bit mysterious to me. Does "initial" mean each time the system is started?

Comment: @Bordaigorl I'm not sure. I think it means each time that indicator is started. I'll experiment a bit when I get to a PC.